# $-\operatorname{sup}(A)$ is it missing something?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

There's something that I don't get in this exercise:

> Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be nonempty and bounded above. Prove that $\operatorname{inf}\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}:-x\in A\rbrace  = -\operatorname{sup}(A)$.

I can assume e.g. $A = \lbrace1,2,3 \rbrace$ in which case $\operatorname{sup}(A)=3$ but $\operatorname{inf}\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}:-x\in A\rbrace = \operatorname{inf}\lbrace \rbrace$ is empty. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you say that $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid-x\in A\}=\emptyset$?

Comment: Ah wait, I think I can see my error now, it's then $\operatorname{inf}\lbrace -3,-2,-1 \rbrace$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $A = \{1,2,3\}$, then

$$\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}:-x\in A\rbrace = \{-1,-2-3\}$$

as $-1,-2,-3 \in \mathbb{R}$, and each of their negations are in $A$.

Comment: Got it, got it.